# IDAPython: idaapi.get_highlight for demangled names

Tags: ida, idapython, idapro-sdk, ida-plugin

I'm using the following code to get the address of the selected function/variable:

```
hightlight = idaapi.get_highlight(idaapi.get_current_viewer())
screen_ea = idaapi.get_screen_ea()
ea = idaapi.get_name_ea(screen_ea, name)
```

It works like a charm except until you meet demangled name in IDA View :(

For example, for this line

```
.text:00406744                 call    KBTickCount(void)
```

idaapi.get_name_ea call would never return the proper address, because the real name is ?KBTickCount@@YIJXZ.

I know that I can just change demangled names representation in IDA Pro, but I'm working on a public plugin and I'm thinking about end users.

And I also want to make it work in Pseudocode view, where all names are demangled.

Any ideas on how to get the address of the selected function/variable for a particular line?

Comment: On what action/event does your code execute?

Comment: I set hotkey action handler if it matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All action callbacks receive a context pointer with various information pre-filled:

```
  ea_t cur_ea;           ///< the current EA of the position in the view
  uval_t cur_value;      ///< the possible address, or value the cursor is positioned on

  func_t *cur_func;      ///< the current function
  func_t *cur_fchunk;    ///< the current function chunk

  struc_t *cur_struc;    ///< the current structure
  member_t *cur_strmem;  ///< the current structure member

  enum_t cur_enum;       ///< the current enum

  segment_t *cur_seg;    ///< the current segment
```

(from `kernwin.hpp`)

So you can just use `ctx.cur_value` (or its Python synonym, `cur_extracted_ea`) to directly get the address/value/identifier under cursor, without having to resolve it yourself.

Comment: Didn't know about that, thank you very much!